# Здравствуйте, как заменить input [type=submit] на button [type=submit]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Здравствуйте, как заменить `input [type=submit]` на `button [type=submit]` через `javascript`, `input` кнопки невидимы и обычным способом их не заменить, а требуется сделать хорошее оформление для кнопок с `before` и `after`, на странице их несколько, `replacewidth` не помог.

Comment: Добавте ваш код, это облегчит ответ на вопрос.

Comment: А суть замены через js, когда можно просто html отредактировать?

Comment: Надеюсь опечатка только тут? replace**w**i**d**th

Comment: А почему вы решили что к `input[type=submit]` нельзя применить псевдо классы `before` и `after`

Comment: Обычным способом их не заменить, их нельзя просто так отредактировать,  Евгений Миронов replaceWith,  0xdb  <input class="btn-block" name="sbm" type="submit" value="Отправить">

Comment: Shnur у вас есть идеи как добавить к input[type=submit]  before и after??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Расширяем $.fn.attr для получения списка всех атрибутов (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery)
(function(old) {
  $.fn.attr = function() {
    if(arguments.length === 0) {
      if(this.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      var obj = {};
      $.each(this[0].attributes, function() {
        if(this.specified) {
          obj[this.name] = this.value;
        }
      });
      return obj;
    }

    return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})($.fn.attr);


// Сам input 
var input = $('.btn-block');

// Заменяем на button c сохранением всех атрибутов
input.replaceWith(
  $('<button />')
    .attr(input.attr())
    .text(input.val())
);

// Просто смотрим что получилось
$('<p />').text($('div').html()).appendTo($('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="btn-block" name="sbm" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой хороший ответ, все получилось, все работает.

Comment: Рад помочь, галочку поставьте, что ответ подошел)